# Cannot edit asp textbox value in firefox

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, textbox, cross-browser

I'm currently having a strange issu in my application: I have a form composed of various labels and textboxes, like so:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <asp:Label Text="EDIFÍCIO" runat="server" ID="lblEdificio"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtFax" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
</tr>
```

The textbox default value is given in the server, and that works correctly. However, when i try to edit the value in the screen, the cursor does not appear, and whatever i type is not reflected on the screen. But if i save the value, what i wrote is indeed saved.

Keep in mind this only happens in Firefox and for specific users (i validated and it's not related to user permissions).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there any kind of theming you are doing for users? When you type in the textbox, try Ctrl + A to select all the data, see if there is any data selected in the textbox, if yes than there is some styling issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was able to fix the issue.

I closed the textboxes in divs with style "overflow:auto" and apparently fixed the issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are proverbially some reasons:-
1. Textbox is disabled.
2. Textbox is Readonly.
3. Container of textbox is disabled or readonly.

share you .cs code for better understanding

Comment: if disabled or readonly is the case, than that data must not be saved, as he is saying that typed thing is indeed saved.

Comment: Like Imran Balouch said, it's none of the above, since 1) the values are saved, 2) works in all browsers except firefox and 3) i have a disabled box, and that one has a different look, and cannot be edited in any browser.